# How to customise the textMateRules for multiple themes in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In **VS Code**, I'd like to customise some `textMateRules` the same for multiple themes. For example, both for `Atom One Dark` and `Default Dark+` but without affecting any of the other themes, I'd like to make the `keyword`s *italic*. I can achieve this by duplicating the same settings twice separately for each theme as below

```json
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Atom One Dark]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "scope": [ "keyword" ],
          "settings": { "fontStyle": "italic" }
        }
      ]
    },
    "[Default Dark+]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "scope": [ "keyword" ],
          "settings": { "fontStyle": "italic" }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

How can I only need to set up once for both, without duplicating the rules, especially if there are a lot same rules for the multiple themes? Something like the below (***but which doesn't work though***)

```json
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Atom One Dark] [Default Dark+]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "scope": [ "keyword" ],
          "settings": { "fontStyle": "italic" }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Based on your comments bellow, I think it's worth updating the question to clarify that what you're trying to do is customise "Atom One Dark" and "Default Dark+" without affecting _any of the other themes_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft will add this feature if [`microsoft/vscode#103694`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103694) gets upvoted enough. The behaviour you want is not possible unless you customise every theme.

```
{
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": [ "keyword" ],
        "settings": { "fontStyle": "italic" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

From [this Github page](https://github.com/kosimst/FiraFlott)

First Copy this code to User Setting.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
        "comment",
        "entity.name.type.class", //class names
        "keyword", //import, export, return…
        "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
        "storage.modifier", //static keyword
        "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "italic"
      }
    },
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be excluded from italics (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
        "invalid",
        "keyword.operator",
        "constant.numeric.css",
        "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
        "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
        "constant.numeric.json"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now look closely, in textMateRules you have to define a scope. 
In the scope array, you have to mention which options you want to modify, then, in the setting array of the same scope you can add your style, for example, you want to add fontStyle italic.
Like this.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
        "comment",
        "entity.name.type.class", //class names
        "keyword", //import, export, return…
        "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
        "storage.modifier", //static keyword
        "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "italic"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I edited the answer. Please let me know if you have trouble understanding my words.

Comment: I know the way described in your answer, but it will affect all themes, not just he ones I'm interested. For example, in my case `Atom One Dark`, & `Default Dark+`.

Comment: i would change my `this` to not italic doesnt work else its work . did u know why ?

Comment: here is my config https://gist.github.com/yogithesymbian/c134398c9d5b380bf5d89af8f3878064

Answer (score 3):

From **VSCode** ***1.59***, it supports exactly the way specified in the question now ***:)***, plus supporting the wildcard `*`. See [Extended theme customization syntax](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_59#_extended-theme-customization-syntax)

```JSON
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Atom One Dark] [Default Dark+] [*Monokai*]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "scope": [ "keyword" ],
          "settings": { "fontStyle": "italic" }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

See the answer by Mr.Shuvo. You can make it specific to a loaded Theme like so:

```
{
"folders": [
    {
        "path": "C:\\Users\\Envs\\django2"
    }
],
"settings": {
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "activityBar.background": "#580A42",
        "titleBar.activeBackground": "#7B0E5D",
        "titleBar.activeForeground": "#FFFCFE"
    },
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
            "[Monokai Classic]": { 
                "textMateRules": 
                [
                    {
                        "scope": "string",
                        "settings": {
                                    "foreground": "#FF9900" ,}
                    }
                ]
            },
        }
}
```

}